# How to use lambda in kotlin for anonymous inner class replacement

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I need your help with my kotlin code below (save as Fun.kt)

```
import javax.swing.*
import java.awt.*
import java.awt.event.*

class Amir
{
    fun addActionListener(m:ActionListener)
    {   
    }
}

fun main()
{

    //SUCCESS
    val btnLambda=JButton("LAMBDA")
    btnLambda.addActionListener(){}


    //FAILED
    val mahmud=Amir()
    mahmud.addActionListener(){}

}
```

myquestions is, why this line is succeeded when compiled:

```
btnLambda.addActionListener(){}
```

but this line is failed:

```
mahmud.addActionListener(){}
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Well, because `mahmud` is and instance of `Amir` and the function within Amir `addActionListener` needs an argument of type `ActionListener`

Comment: It doesn't just "fail", you get _a specific error message_. Include it in your question.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to fix this problem.

Either you should call `addActionListener` in another way, because it takes an `ActionListener` *object*, not a *lambda*:

```kotlin
    mahmud.addActionListener(ActionListener {})
```

Or you should change the signature of Amir#addActionListener function to make `addActionListener() {}` syntax valid:

```kotlin
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent
import java.awt.event.ActionListener

class Amir {
    fun addActionListener(action: (e: ActionEvent) -> Unit) {
        val m = ActionListener(action)
    }
}

fun main() {
    val mahmud = Amir()
    mahmud.addActionListener {}
}
```